# Attach large files with laravel Mail Facade

Tags: php, laravel, email

When i am trying to attach large files greater than 1MB this error appears

message :fwrite(): send of 5067 bytes failed with errno=11 Resource temporarily unavailable

file: "/var/www/html/test/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php"

and here is my code

in **module.php**

`Mail::to($data[EMAIL])->send(new SigningApplication($data))`;

in **SigningApplication.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class SigningApplication extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */


    public $user_data;

    public function __construct($user_data)
    {
        $this->user_data = $user_data;

    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {

        return $this->from(config('email'), config('mail.from')['name'])
            ->view('emails.signing_application')
            ->attach($this->user_data['pdf'],['mime' => 'application/pdf'])


    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of values are in `$this->user_data`?

Comment: it includes: username ,pdf_link

Comment: `$user_data = [username => 'name','pdf_link' =>'link_to_file'];`

Comment: Maybe worth changing your mail driver from smtp (I'm assuming?) to sendmail or something and see if it helps.